# Vue.js/React/JSX: How to style a tag using a variable in data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reactjs

I have a html element `textarea_01` to which I want to add a style when I press my `button_01` which has an `onClick` function on it

```
myFunction: function(event) {
//some code that does something
};
```

Since I can't use directives with JSX I was thinking that the following will work:

```
<textarea id="textareaID" style={{resetWidth}}/>
```

And add to my function that's used on the `onClick` my code, so it will look like:

```
myFunction: function(event) {
var textarea = new Vue({
  el: '#textareaID',
  data: {
    resetWidth: 'width: 10px'
  }
})
//some code that does something
};
```

But it's not working and WebStorm tells me

```
You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available
```

How do I work around this and accomplish what I want to do, which is add a css property to a html element after I click on another element ?

Note: Webpack and the followin is used in the code github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx Note that almost all built-in Vue directives are not supported when using JSX, the sole exception being v-show, which can be used with the v-show={value} syntax.

Comment: Be aware that you are using the runtime-only version of Vue which expects any templates to be pre-compiled.

Comment: @varbrad how wo I pre-compile them ?

Comment: Either using `vue-template-compiler`, on just use the compiler version of VueJS. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the `style` attribute to Vue, because you can't use moustaches on tag properties:

```
<textarea id="textareaID" :style="resetWidth" />
```

---

Because you are using runtime only Vue version, you should try with another approach.

Remove the moustaches from the `textarea`:

```
<textarea id="textareaID" />
```

Set the styles for the element with javascript on the `mounted` hook or another [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) that you want:

```
myFunction: function(event) {
    var textarea = new Vue({
        el: '#textareaID',
        data: {
            resetWidth: 'width: 10px'
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$el.setAttribute("style", this.resetWidth);
        },
    })
    //some code that does something
};
```

Comment: error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

Doesn't even start

Comment: @Newcomer Which Vue version are you using?

Comment: "vue-router": "^2.1.1", with Vue 2

Comment: Make sure to use the Runtime+Compiler build of Vue, the runtime only build cannot compile your template markdown into render functions for you.

Comment: Take a look at what @varbrad says. My solution would work if you were using vue component files.

Comment: @GerardReches I can't use Vue compiling, because of webpack. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: @Newcomer You say you're using webpack or that you are not using webpack?

Comment: @GerardReches Yes, using webpack.

Comment: @Newcomer So what is the problem? I'm using webpack too, with the full Vue build.

Comment: @GerardReches https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx
Note that almost all built-in Vue directives are not supported when using JSX, the sole exception being v-show, which can be used with the v-show={value} syntax.
Because of this.

Comment: @Newcomer If you need that for some kind of compatibility with React, I can't help with that. I have no more than very basic React experience and I really don't like JSX syntax, that's why I love Vue templates.

Comment: @GerardReches yes, unfortunately I can't change what is used in the code, I just need to figure out how to solve the issue with what I have.

Comment: @Newcomer Updated answer, try if that helps.

Comment: @GerardReches Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$el.setAttribute is not a function"

Seems to me that I can't use another new Vue declaration inside a function as well or something, what's going on...

Comment: @Newcomer Replace the line with `console.log(this.$el)` and check if it outputs a DOM element.